# Update background variables for all users

Tags: discord.js, quick.db

I’m using discord.js and quick.db and was trying to figure out if there was a way to update a variable for each person every 5 minutes. For example, if someone had three workers they would earn 15 dollars every 5 minutes. At the same time if someone had 1 worker they would earn only 5 dollars every 5 minutes. Is this possible?

This is the code to make it run every five minutes:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    client.commands.get('mupdates').execute(message, Discord);
    console.log('main')
}, 15000);
```

This is the code that is being called:

```js
const db = require('quick.db');
    
module.exports = {
    name: 'mupdates',
    description: 'updates variables every five minutes',
    execute: async (message, Discord) => {
        let target = message.mentions.members.first() || message.author
        let workers = await db.fetch(`workers_${target}`)
    
        console.log('eeeeeeeeeeeeee')

        db.add(`newmoney_${target}`, workers)
        console.log(`gave ${workers} money to ${target}`)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you done research and tried to achieve this on your own? Stack Overflow is not intended to give yes/no answers, but rather help you debug already existing code.

Comment: yes I've done lots of research and coding and can't figure anything out

Comment: Show some code you've got :)

Comment: Updated the original post to show code

Comment: Your command executes automatically every 15 seconds. Target expects either a mention or a message author. If the command executes by itself without a message, where do the mentions or author come from?

Comment: the 15 seconds was just for testing forgot to update it for this, and i don't know any other ways to find the IDs. Somehow it still gets people's IDs though it just runs it for them multiple times